# Может ли вызов моего метода в цикле вызвать переполнение стека?

Tags: c++

Может ли вызов этого метода в цикле вызвать переполнение стека?
И если да, то как это решить?

```
Queue Queue::operator <<(Time &time) {
    Element *temp = new Element;
    temp->time = time;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else
        head = tail = temp;
    size++;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Нет, этот код использует только кучу, которая может переполниться. Стек в нем при цикле не растет. У Вас происходит выделение в стек только переменной `Element *temp`, которая при выходе сразу уничтожается и так будет по кругу.

Comment: Почему вы грешите именно на него? Может, в этом цикле еще что-то есть такое... сомнительное?

Comment: MVS выбивает мне такой эксепшн
Unhandled exception at 0x777EDEDF (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication10.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00192FFC).
При попытке вызвать этот метод.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос какой-то некорректный. Если вызывать любое создание новых элементов, на которые идет выделение памяти, в цикле, то рано или поздно память вся будет забита, выдаст переполнение стека. 
Если Вам нужно вызвать этот метод в небольшом цикле, то все будет работать нормально, но все равно зависит от машины. А если бесконечном цикле, тут все понятно.

Для подстраховки, советую сделать какое-то ограничение на размер очереди. И при попытке добавить новый элемент в очередь, проверят size.